# Should I be worried about the time I reply to a request for interview?

Tags: interviewing, correspondence, time

At around 4 pm Monday, a company I applied to almost a month ago suddenly replied that they would like to interview me on Thursday. However, I am in a class and busy doing homework throughout that day so didn't see and respond to that email at 11:45 am today (Tuesday). As of now (2:30 pm on Tuesday) there is no response to my confirmation of that interview request like "see you soon" from that company. Should I be worried?

Comment: no. You answered in a reasonable amount of time (up to a day, usually). Now give them a reasonable amount of time (a day or so) to answer before you even *start* to get nervous.

Comment: **Should I be worried?** - Worried about what, exactly? If we say yes, what does that mean to you? If we say no, what does that mean to you? What are you trying to ascertain with this question?

Comment: I am trying to plan p

Answer (score 7):

So, they sent an email close to the end of the working day, you responded the following day, before midday.

Completely fine. This is pretty standard.

If you are super worried, you could always follow up with a Phone Call:

"Hey, just calling to confirm my Interview is scheduled for this time/date?" - which is completely fine.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I be worried?

No.

It took you almost 20 hours to reply to their original message because you were occupied with other things.  It has been less that 3 hours since they would have received your reply.  Just like you, they can be occupied with other things.

Wait it out until tomorrow, and if you have not heard back you should reach out to them ( with a phone call ) for a follow up since the interview is presumably the next day.

Comment: Why the need to follow up? They sent an invite, OP sent an RSVP to that invite. What more confirmation is needed for either party to understand that the other party will be present during the scheduled time?

Comment: I would say it depends on how the invitation was worded. If it was an informal query along the lines of "We are wondering if you can make it to an interview, e.g. on Monday 2pm next week", I think I would expect a confirmation from them. (At the same time, if I show up and find I don't have an appointment, I would consider it unprofessional from them.) If it was a "We would like to meet you Monday 2.pm, such-and-such people will be present", I wouldn't necessarily expect a confirmation from them (but still appreciate one).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't worry! During an interview process and after the first two interviews, I was waiting for a reply. Almost 2 weeks passed, got an e-mail at almost 8pm to schedule the final interview (acceptance and discussion of terms) on the next day. They of course apologised for the delay and time.

In my opinion, a company cannot expect someone to give/do more than what they themselves give/do.

> I applied to almost a month ago suddenly replied (4 PM Monday)

> Respond to that email at 11:45 am today (Tuesday)

You responded within the first day, which is already fast. The shorter the time they give to schedule (Late Monday sent, Thursday to schedule), the more reasonable it is to having a reschedule due to timing problems from one of the sides.